# C#: Get unix timestamp with microseconds

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

How can I get the current unix timestamp in microseconds in .NET 5? I have looked around and only found a way to get it in milliseconds with [`ToUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0), and nothing that would include microseconds.

Comment: Why do you want this? It matters. A Unix timestamp is somewhat loosely defined and essentially an implementation detail. All .NET libraries work with dates. All databases have date types.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: There are plenty of places where a Unix timestamp is used in communicating. It being an epoch for a library may be an implementation detail, but when it's part of an API specification, it's not.

Comment: If you really want a Unix timestamp in microseconds you can use the `Ticks` property of `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` which counts in 100ns increments since 0001-01-01. To use 1970 as a base you'll have to subtract it from the current time, and then multiple the Ticks of the result by 10

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Exactly - and that's the answer I'm writing. (Except divide by 10 rather than multiply.)

Comment: @JonSkeet quite often though a Unix timestamp is used because people assume it's a standard, or because some legacy system does it this way.

Comment: What did you try so far? You can really easily rewrite the `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` [implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/DateTimeOffset.cs,629) by using `TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000` for the result (same for the base epoch time)

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg that won't produce the missing microseconds

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: yes it would. (`UtcDateTime.Ticks / (TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000)`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to subtract the Unix epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) from the `DateTimeOffset` to get a `TimeSpan`, then get the microseconds from that by dividing the total number of ticks by 10:

```cs
using System;

public static class DateTimeOffsetExtensions
{
    private static readonly DateTimeOffset UnixEpoch =
        new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);

    public static long ToUnixTimeMicroseconds(this DateTimeOffset timestamp)
    {
        TimeSpan duration = timestamp - UnixEpoch;
        // There are 10 ticks per microsecond.
        return duration.Ticks / 10;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        Console.WriteLine(now.ToUnixTimeMicroseconds());
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely this is the way. But still thinking the user needs current timestamp in microseconds

Comment: But pleeease Jon, don't you already have enough score? :D Instead of answering immediately, I was trying to make him realize how to do that by linking the source of the method he already found. Ah, nevermind. A nice answer btw.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli: If they need the current timestamp in microseconds, they can use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMicroseconds()`, which is basically what the sample code does.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right! I can't upvote you twice :( :D

Comment: Apologies in advance, but the comment in code should be "There are 10 ticks per microsecond". [The tick is equal to 100 nanoseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks?view=net-6.0#remarks). The calculation is right, but the comment is a bit misleading.

Comment: @omajid: Yup, absolutely - fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. `Main` should be public in your example, right?

Comment: @gshpychka: No, it doesn't need to be. Even the `Test` class doesn't need to be public.

Comment: The number of ticks per microsecond is not always 10, so hardcoding it would give wrong results in some environments (like on AWS EC2 instances).

Comment: @gshpychka: No, it really is. See the remarks section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.ticks?view=net-6.0. "The value of the Ticks property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight on January 1, 0001 (the value of MinValue)." Note that this is `DateTimeOffset.Ticks` - if we were talking about `Stopwatch.Ticks`, that would be a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad, thanks a lot!